# Deregister AMI and delete snapshot Automatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ami

```py
import boto3
from dateutil.parser import parse

import datetime

client = boto3.client('ec2')
delete_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1).date()

def handler(event, context):

    def days_old(date):
        get_date_obj = parse(date)
        date_obj = get_date_obj.replace(tzinfo=None)
        diff = datetime.datetime.now() - date_obj
        return diff.days

    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    amis = ec2.describe_images(Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'AMI name',
            'Values': ['Lambda -*']
        }
    ])

    # Filter AMI-ID and Snapshot-ID
    for ami in amis['Images']:
        create_date = ami['CreationDate']
        ami_id = ami['ImageId']
        day_old = days_old(create_date)
        if day_old >= (datetime.datetime.now().date() - delete_date).days:
            print("Deleting -> " + ami_id + " - Created on " + create_date)
            # Deregister the AMI
            ec2.deregister_image(ImageId=ami_id)

            # Delete the associated snapshots
            for device in ami['BlockDeviceMappings']:
                snapshot_id = device['Ebs']['SnapshotId']
             

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'AMIs and their snapshots deleted successfully'
    }
```

I want to deregister all the AMIs and delete the snapshot associated with it, which are created before a specific date.
what are the possible changes I can do to make it work?

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "requestId": "8627adcd-0a5e-4c1a-a88b-c0cae8e09a8e",
  "stackTrace": []
}

I am getting this error in output.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check lastLaunchedTime AMI attribute.

```
res = client.describe_image_attribute(
                         Attribute='lastLaunchedTime',
                         ImageId='ami-xxxxxx'
                     )
lastLaunchedTime = res['LastLaunchedTime']['Value']
```